# Java regex find method returns false for matching roman numerals

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to create a regex pattern in java to match list text which has certain attributes. For example :

> ```
> (i) hello stackoverflow
>
> (iv) hello user
> ```

The list can either match `(i)` or `i)`.
I have arrived at a pattern using my understanding of regex and tested that version in an online tool and it returns the correct result. However when i implement it in java the pattern matcher returns false for find method.

Here is the psudo-code:'

```
String text = "(i) hello";
String romanNumeralsRegex = "^(\\(|\\[)?((v|x)?i[xv]|(xv|v|x)?i+|(xv|v|x))((\\)|\\]|\\.))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(romanNumeralsRegex );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

The matcher.find() method is returning false. As per my understanding the matcher should return `group(0)` as **`(i)`**. I don't know where I have gone wrong. Requesting help from the community here

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the output for matcher.find() returns true for me

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz thats wierd because it returns false for me.

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks correct to me, except you need to call `Matcher#group` after you call `Matcher#find`:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
(i)
```

Comment: Like I said the matcher.find() returns false.

Comment: It returns `true` for me.